# Cycle http requests monitor

Tags: monitoring

How I can monitor cycle http requests by linux and store IP which scan my site?
I need to find all scanners with copies of my site content.

example. If IP 192.168.1.1 open index.php every 1 minute, - add 192.168.1.1 IP to scanner.txt

Comment: Which distro are you using? Assuming you run apache can't you just grep httpacess.log?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: @vfbsilva I use Ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm.  Parsing nginx logs - Good idea.